# Standard predicates for STL count_if

Tags: stl, vector, c++

I'm using the STL function count_if to count all the positive values 
in a vector of doubles. For example my code is something like:

```
 vector<double> Array(1,1.0)

 Array.push_back(-1.0);
 Array.push_back(1.0);  

 cout << count_if(Array.begin(), Array.end(), isPositive);
```

where the function isPositive is defined as

```
 bool isPositive(double x) 
 {
     return (x>0); 
 }
```

The following code would return 2. Is there a way of doing the above 
without writting my own function isPositive? Is there a built-in
function I could use?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7z5x4b(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind1st(std::less<double>(), 0))` is what you want.

If you're already `using namespace std`, the clearer version reads

```
count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), bind1st(less<double>(), 0));
```

All this stuff belongs to the `<functional>` header, alongside other standard predicates.

Comment: Or you could `bind2nd(greater<double>(), 0)`.  The choice is yours!

Comment: Given he's already `using namespace std;` it'd be clearer without all the `std::` prefixes.

Comment: An elegant solution. What if I also need to count all non-negative values?

Comment: @Wawel100 - there is a std::greater_equal predicate too.

Comment: Edited to match your comments.

Answer (score 12):

If you are compiling with MSVC++ 2010 or GCC 4.5+ you can use *real* lambda functions:

```
std::count_if(Array.begin(), Array.end(), [](double d) { return d > 0; });
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is a build-in function.
However, you could use boost lambda http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/lambda.html
to write it :

```
cout << count_if(Array.begin(), Array.end(), _1 > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cout<<std::count_if (Array.begin(),Array.end(),std::bind2nd (std::greater<double>(),0)) ;  
greater_equal<type>()  -> if >= 0
```